# How to access child components value (in a ListView) in parent component in React Native

Tags: react-native, reactjs

My app has a list view that render a list of items.

[image: Screenshot]

Every click of my child component triggers a change in state value

```
{ selected: !this.state.selected }
```

In the image above I have selected 2 child items, how can I access their value in my parent component?

For instance,

```
Big Data: true
IoT: true
```

This is my parent snippet, [Hosted on Github too](https://github.com/rexlow/Devent/blob/master/src/containers/tabContainers/Profile/AddInterest.js)

```
import InterestItem from './InterestItem';

class AddInterest extends Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    this.createDataSource(this.props);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.createDataSource(nextProps);
  }

  createDataSource({ items }) {
    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({
      rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2
    });
    this.dataSource = ds.cloneWithRows(items);
  }

  //return arrays of event from events
  renderRow(item) {
    return <InterestItem item={item} icon={computer} />;
  }

  render() {
    const { centerEverything, skeleton, container, textContainer, contentContainer, listViewContainer,
      titleContainer, descContainer, title, desc, submitContainer, submitTitle } = styles;
    return (
      <View style={[container]}>
        <View style={[centerEverything, textContainer]}>
          <View style={titleContainer}>
            <Text style={[title]}>What kind of events are you interest in?</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={descContainer}>
            <Text style={[desc]}>You'll see more events from the categories you choose.</Text>
          </View>
        </View>

        <View style={[contentContainer]}>
          <ListView
            enableEmptySections
            contentContainerStyle={listViewContainer}
            dataSource={this.dataSource}
            renderRow={this.renderRow}
          />
        </View>

        <View style={[centerEverything, {paddingBottom: 10}]}>
          <View style={[centerEverything, submitContainer]}>
            <Text style={submitTitle}>Submit</Text>
          </View>
        </View>

      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

This is my child component, [Hosted on GitHub too](https://github.com/rexlow/Devent/blob/master/src/containers/tabContainers/Profile/InterestItem.js)

```
class InterestItem extends Component {

  state = {
    selected: false
  }

  render() {
    const { skeleton, centerEverything, container, textStyle } = styles;
    return(
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => this.setState({ selected: !this.state.selected })}>
        <View style={[centerEverything, container, { backgroundColor: this.state.selected ? '#635eb4' : '#e7e7e7'}]}>
          {this.props.icon}
          <Text style={textStyle}>{this.props.item[0]}</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    )
  }
}
```

Upon request from @freesoul, here's the child instances (considering I have 8 children)
[image]

Comment: Consider a single instance of `InterestItem`, what can be the value of `this.props.item`? Can you post an example?

Comment: @free-soul I have added the requested information

Comment: My suggestion is that you should maintain the state of children in your parent; something like `state = { cars: false, bigData: true, hackintosh: false, iot: true, ... }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following up on @free-soul, I would do the following modifications to your code:

```
constructor(){
    this.state = {
    //...
        rowStates: {} // Holds the state for each row, identified by the uid property (I'm assuming it is unique, otherwise use some other value)
    }
    this.renderRow = this.renderRow.bind(this);
    this.rowUpdated = this.rowUpdated.bind(this);
}
renderRow(item) {
   // Adds a callback so that we know when an element has been pressed
    return <InterestItem item={item} icon={computer} onPress={() => this.rowUpdated(item)}/>;
}

rowUpdated(item){
     let rowStates = {...this.state.rowStates}; // Make a copy of the object
     rowStates[item.uid] = !rowStates[item.uid];  // If the item is not in the object, !undefined will be evaluated, which results in true, so the operation is safe
     this.setState({rowStates});
}
```

Then, your child component should look like this:

```
class InterestItem extends Component {

  state = {
    selected: false
  }

  render() {
    const { skeleton, centerEverything, container, textStyle } = styles;
    return(
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => {this.setState({ selected: !this.state.selected }); if(this.props.onPress) this.props.onPress(this.props.item)}}>
        <View style={[centerEverything, container, { backgroundColor: this.state.selected ? '#635eb4' : '#e7e7e7'}]}>
          {this.props.icon}
          <Text style={textStyle}>{this.props.item[0]}</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    )
  }
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I'm afraid rowStates = {} is invalid, react native complains about an error during runtime. State cannot be null?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it was very helpful, though there are 2 mistakes. rowStates: {} and inside renderRow onPress method, we should return in fat arrow function, onPress={() => rowUpdated(item)} otherwise the app will run the method automatically

Comment: Uh, sorry! Didn't notice when writing. I've edited the answer to correct the mistakes.